# Code executes automatic and not on button click

Tags: google-apps-script

I modified a piece of code and HTML from Khizer Mehmood. Great piece of coding, will include link. It does almost all I need. But it triggers a Geolocation directly, I want to add information to one more column and then send this in to Sheets.

I dont know how to modify this HTML and code so that it will prompt me to add information before sending it all to Google Sheets

Here's my code:

#### JavaScript:

```js
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getLoc(value) {
    var SpreadSheetKey = "1NDDhHomd4uJ8Xc2OlmK_jtShCKRLuHrwMBieURtM8zo";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKey);
    var respSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var data = respSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var headers = data[0];
    //var numColumns = headers.length ;
    var numResponses = data.length;
    var c = value[0];
    var d = value[1];
    var e = c + "," + d; {
        respSheet.getRange(numResponses + 1, 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        respSheet.getRange(numResponses + 1, 2).setValue(e);
        var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(value[0], value[1]);
        f = response.results[0].formatted_address;
        respSheet.getRange(numResponses + 1, 3).setValue(f);

    }
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <script>
      (function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
      })()
      function showPosition(position) {
       var a= position.coords.latitude;
       var b= position.coords.longitude;
       var c=[a,b]
       getPos(c)
       function getPos(value) {
       google.script.run.getLoc(value);
       }
      }
   </script>
   <button onclick="myFeed">Copy Text</button>
   <body>
      <h2>Thank you!</h2>
      <p> Your registration is complete. Have a great day! </p>
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1wheniE0HFtA37frkolHfmnjRLFbNkTI3" alt="W3Schools.com" style="width:100px;height:120px;">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post the code here, please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I figured out how to add the code correctly. I think. But the HTML still eludes med. Hope someone could still help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the JS inside your HTML. You are using an ["Immediately Invoked Function Expression"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). By wrapping the function `getLocation()` between parentheses, you are telling the browser to execute the expression. Hence you get this done immediately.

#### Solution:

Remove the parentheses, and call the function when the button is clicked.

#### Example:

Add the following button to your HTML:

`<button onclick="getLocation">Get Location</button>`

Comment: This unfortunately does nothing. When () are removed nothing is instead transferred to Google sheets. Pressing the button does not trigger the geolocation to be inserted in sheet.

Comment: Which button are you pressing?

Comment: I added your line <button onclick="getLocation">Get Location</button> to my HTML and used that one.

Comment: It works! i needed to remove not only the () that wrapped the function but also the () at the end of getLocation. Thank you!

Comment: Could I ask for help adding a inputbox which populates the 4th column in my sheet as well? Or should I make that another query?

Comment: Glad to help!. It's best to make another query, as newer questions get more views from the community ;).

Comment: Really appreciate it :)